# how to scrape data from a link after login once

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I have developed a script which run after few minutes and get the data. Each time I have to first login and then get the data from the specific link. I just want to know how I can get the data from specific link after login only once and not to login each time.

the login page generate automatic hidden field name "testname" so I first **scrape** the login page and get that hidden field

Scraping login page to get hidden field.

```
<?php
$url="http://www.example.com/login";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$cookie = 'cookies.txt';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,       $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,      $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);

$result3 = preg_match('/<input type="hidden" name="testname" value=" (.*?)"/', $content, $matches);

//Script to login the page after getting hidden field from login page and I want to login only once this code and do not login each time

$fields=array('testname'=>$matches[1],'email' => 'username', 'password' => 'password','btnLogin'=>'login');

$url1 = "http://www.example.com/comapny/index.php";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
$timeout = 30;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,         10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,  $timeout );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,       $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,      $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// After login I want to get the data from below link after every 10min

$url1="http://www.example.com/abc/detail.php";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,       $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,      $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   //#Login and save data in cookie file

    $curl=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "path");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    //# Use cookie data using CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE

    $curl=curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "path");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflat');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
```